# Какие неймспейсы используются в Prism 6 для регионов?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-10, uwp, prism

Какие неймспейсы надо указывать в представлениях контролов, которые я хочу использовать, как заполнители регионов?

В призм 5, судя по гуглу, надо было указывать

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions; assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition"
```

и пользоваться как-то так:

```
<ItemsControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="CustomerRegion"  />
```

А какой неймспейс указывать в 6?

В существующем нет нужного.

```
xmlns:prism="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
```

P.S. У кого достаточно прав - поставьте, пожалуйста, под этим вопросом тег Prism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам себе отвечаю опять. 
Разработчик Prism Brian Lagunas сказал, что регионы в UWP не поддерживаются.